# Google Deploy Manager (Invalid config files: Template fetching failed / Failed to find resource)

Tags: google-compute-engine

When using Google Deploy Manager:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create  my-environment --config my-environment.jinja
```

I get the following errors:

> ErrorsValueListEntry INVALID_CONFIG
>
> Invalid config files: Template fetching failed: Failed to find resource

Regardless of the content of my `my-environment.jinja` - even when copying the samples found [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/step-by-step-guide/create-a-configuration)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Deployment Manager command-line tool treats templates (determined by `.jinja` and `.py` file extensions) differently than a top-level config (which can have any other file extension) as inputs to the `--config` flag.

If the input configuration is a template, the tool will look for its sub-imports to be defined in the template's schema file (e.g., `foo.jinja.schema`), rather than in the configuration itself as is done with top-level YAML configs.

My guess is the error snippet above is incomplete, and the full error contains details about which template it is failing to find. Likely that is a sub-template that wasn't properly imported.

### Example

#### Top-level Config

A top-level YAML configuration, `my-environment.yaml`, may look like:

```
imports
- path: sub-template.jinja

resources:
- name: sub-template
  type: sub-template.jinja
```

This is deployed with the command:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create env --config my-environment.yaml
```

#### Template

The template `my-environment.jinja` would be defined as:

```
resources:
- name: sub-template
  type: sub-template.jinja
```

with a separate file, `my-environment.jinja.schema`, defining property schema and imports:

```
imports:
- path: sub-template.jinja
```

This can be deployed with the command:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create env --config my-environment.jinja
```

and can even take properties from the command-line with `--properties`.

See [Using Schemas](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/configuration/using-schemas) in the Deployment Manager documentation for more info on schemas.

Comment: The lack of schema was my problem indeed

Comment: HEY GOOGLE: would have been nice if you documented this.

Comment: Is there a way to import all files in a subdirectory instead of having to list them all explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out while your sub-templates should be named `*.jinja` or `*.py` the main deployment file (even though it contains jinja code) should be be named `.yaml`

`my-environment.jinja` should therefor be `my-environment.yaml` **but only for the main deployment file**. The templates should still be named `*.jinja`

*Since Google Deployment Manager is not too well used today it lacks Q&A on common problems. Putting this out there for Google (and users) to find.*